# jQuery sortable not working with pagination in AngularJS table

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angular-material

I am working on a dashboard in which I have a table with pagination. This table (angular-material), created using the md-data-table (found on: https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) displays project information and has a couple fields such as:

- Project number
- Project title
- Project budget
- Project status

I am using a jQuery sortable plugin found on (http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) in order to be able to change the order of my table columns using drag and drop. This works perfectly, I am able to change the order of columns, and the data underneath changes positions as well.

The issue occurs once I change my table from let's say page 1 to page 2. The column head order is remembered, the data however is displayed incorrectly. For example if I swapped the project status with the project budget, the status will be displayed under budget, and the budget will be displayed under status. As soon as I go back from page 2 to page 1, the data is also displayed in the incorrect order over there.

An example of what this looks like:

[image][image]

I think the issue has to do with the fact that my html tells how the table should be ordered and filled, however I may be wrong. If you have encountered a similar issue in the past, please let me know where it goes wrong, and what the best way to fix this is.

My table head looks as follows (this is what I use to change the order of columns using drag and drop):

```
<thead md-head class="sorted_head" md-order="myOrder" 
 style="width:100%">
        <tr md-row style="background-color:rgba(0,74,102,0.6)">
            <th class="doColor" md-column>
                <span>Nr.</span>
            </th>
            <th md-column>
                <span>Project Name</span>
            </th>
            <th md-column md-numeric>
                <span>Budget</span>
            </th>
            <th md-column md-numeric>
                <span>Status</span>
            </th>
</thead>
```

My table body looks as follows:

```
<tbody md-body data-ng-switch on="dayDataCollapse[$index]" style="background-color: rgba(0,74,102,0.1)">
        <tr class="clickableRow" ng-class-odd="'oddRow'" ng-class-even="'evenRow'" style="padding: 0!important"
            md-row md-select="project"
            md-select-id="title" md-auto-select
            ng-repeat-start="project in filtered = (projects.data | orderBy : myOrder | filter:projectSearch) |
            limitTo: query.limit: (query.page - 1) * query.limit">
            <td md-cell>{{project.project_nr}}</td>
            <td md-cell style="padding-left:5px!important"
                ng-class="{selectedProject : project.selected == true}"
                ng-click="project.selected = !project.selected"
                ng-bind-html="decodeHTML(project.title)"></td>
            <td md-cell ng-show="budget_checked">€ {{project.budget_indication}}</td>
            <td md-cell ng-show="performance_checked" class="clickableRow clickableHover"
                ng-click="showCpiDialog($event, project)"><i
                    class="material-icons">
                fiber_manual_record</i>{{project.total_cpi[project.total_cpi.length-1].cpi > 0 ?
                project.total_cpi[project.total_cpi.length-1].cpi * 100 : ' ' | ceil}}
            </td>
</tbody>
```

My table pagination looks as follows:

```
<md-table-pagination
        id="paginationId"
        md-size="15"
        md-limit="query.limit"
        md-limit-options="[15, 30, 45, 75, 100]"
        md-page="query.page"
        md-total="{{filtered.length}}"
        md-page-select
        ng-click="saveSelectedRows()">
</md-table-pagination>
```

The jQuery code (makes use of another file which is too big to add):

```
var oldIndex;
    $('.sorted_head tr').sortable({
        containerSelector: 'tr',
        itemSelector: 'th',
        // placeholder: '<tr md-row class="placeholder">test</tr>',
        vertical: false,
        onDragStart: function ($item, container, _super) {
            oldIndex = $item.index();
            $item.appendTo($item.parent());
            _super($item, container);
        },
        onDrop: function  ($item, container, _super) {
            var field, newIndex = $item.index();

            if(newIndex != oldIndex) {
                $item.closest('table').find('tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
                    row = $(row);
                    if(newIndex < oldIndex) {
                        row.children().eq(newIndex).before(row.children()[oldIndex]);
                    } else if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
                        row.children().eq(newIndex).after(row.children()[oldIndex]);
                    }
                });
            }

            _super($item, container);
        }
    });
```